# Classic ASP with Oracle Database

Tags: html, oracle, asp-classic

I am new to Classic ASP. Since last week I am working with this technology. Could you please help me on the following questions with simple examples.

Questions:

1. Fetching some data from oracle database and displaying it in various textbox controls and labels.
2. View and updating the data.
3. How to fecth the database table and display it in a grid or any control.

I have done some R&D but am unable to get the exact flow of it. It's totally insane so help me on this. Please suggest me some websites or links to get more into it.

Thanks for your time.

-Padmanaban

Comment: Are you sure it's [Classic ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) you mean and not [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET)?

Comment: Yes its classic asp only... I am have an idea about ASP.Net not about ASP!

Comment: @Paul could you please help me to understand this lines of code from [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10676/Class-implementation-for-using-webservices-in-ASP) i.e. where i have to give those piece of code and how to create it from the scratch.? ? for my sake, I have asked this same question to christof also.. Please post your comments.. it would be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ADO

Here some tutorials :

http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_examples.asp

Specific to oracle :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255043

Comment: Thanks for your help christof13... But i am not able to get it i have browsed those links i need some live example from u al... If you have time please do the favr..

Comment: could you please help me to understand this lines of code from [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10676/Class-implementation-for-using-webservices-in-ASP) i.e. where i have to give those piece of code and how to create it from the scratch.? ? Please help